# How to use Intel register name in Doxygen?

Tags: escaping, doxygen

In Intel assembly, registers are denoted by labels like "%eax". 
If I do have in the source the text "\%eax %eax", in the HTML output file I see the text "%eax eax", as expected.

If I have the text "@subsection RegisterAX \%eax" in the source, in the corresponding subtitle line of the HTML output "%eax" appears, as expected. However, when I use "@ref RegisterAX" in the source, the corresponding output is "eax", rather than "%eax", as I expect. Do I wrong something?

Comment: What happens when you use \ref RegisterAX "%eax" ? Which version of doxygen are you using?

Comment: That is it, thanks! The version is 1.8.6. Any idea, where the "\%" disappears?

Comment: It probably disappears when the section description is taken as default for the ref. As a side note: current version is 1.8.11 (but still has this "problem")